# $1+e^{ix}+e^{i2x}+...+e^{inx}=\frac{(1-e^{i(n+1)x})(1-e^{-ix})}{(1-\cos(x))^2+\sin^2(x)}, n\in \mathbb{N}, x\neq 2k\pi , k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show

$$1+e^{ix}+e^{i2x}+...+e^{inx}=\frac{(1-e^{i(n+1)x})(1-e^{-ix})}{(1-\cos(x))^2+\sin^2(x)}, n\in \mathbb{N}, x\neq 2k\pi , k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

I have tried to simplify the denominator, which turned out to be $2-2 \cos(x). $

Moreover, the numerator seems to turn out to be $1-e^{(-ix)}-e^{i (1+n) x}+e^{-i x+i (1+n) x}$.

But this does not seem to lead to anywhere.

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the geometric series formula on the left hand side? This simplifies the equation a lot, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that, for every $\alpha\in\Bbb C,\;\;\alpha\neq1$ you have that
$$
1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\cdots+\alpha^{n+1}=\frac{1-\alpha^{n+1}}{1-\alpha}
$$
being $x\neq2k\pi,\;\alpha=e^{ix}\neq1$ so LHS is
$$
\frac{1-e^{ix(n+1)}}{1-e^{ix}}
$$
multiply this by $\frac{1-e^{-ix}}{1-e^{-ix}}$. Hence it remains to check only the denominator:
$$
(1-e^{ix})(1-e^{-ix})=2-2\frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}2=2-2\cos x
$$
but this is equal to the denominator of RHS, as you discovered by your own.

Comment: Awesome. However, how do you prove that the geometric series formula works for complex number in the form of z=x+iy? Thanks!

Comment: Because every complex number $z=a+ib$ can be written in the polar form $re^{i\theta}$: just take $r=|z|$ and $\theta=\operatorname{arg}z$.